# Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for multiply operator error

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am getting this error when I run (this part) of the following query in SQL Management Studio. Can someone help? Do I need to change the query to see this as a different value?

```
sum(a.UNITCST * a.PRICEQTY) AWP,
sum(a.CLTINGRCST) INGRD_CST,
sum(a.CLTDISPFEE) DF
```

Comment: Can you solve: `hghe * 6 = ?` Neither can SQL Server - you can't multiple non-numbers, as the error says - nvarchars are invalid for multiplying. Try to  change your column to a number format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your fields are text (char) fields, you should use [CAST/CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) or [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) before to use it on numeric operations.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TEST (A VARCHAR(10), B VARCHAR(10), C DECIMAL(18,2));
> INSERT INTO TEST VALUES 
> ('10.2', '20.2', 5.5),
> ('5.2', '7.4', 10.0);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT SUM(A * C) F1, 
>        SUM(B),
>        SUM(C)
> FROM   TEST;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Msg 8117 Level 16 State 1 Line 2
> Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.
> ```

> ```
> SELECT SUM(TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), A) * C) F1, 
>        SUM(TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), B)) F2,
>        SUM(C) F3
> FROM   TEST;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> F1       | F2    | F3   
> :------- | :---- | :----
> 108.1000 | 27.60 | 15.50
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a954958f90e6c6ffdb18cf7e4651a734)*

Comment: Hopefully the Ops column contains only valid numbers +1 from me.

Comment: ...and if some of the values in the column might be strings - even if you filter them out - you may have to use a `CASE` expression or `TRY_CONVERT()` to avoid conversion errors.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear one of your columns is an nvarchar(), you'll need to cast it to a number prior to multiplying.

```
a.UNITCST*a.PRICEQTY
```